# PHP How to replace part of a file's hex in binary?

Tags: php

So just a precursor, a lot of the solutions already on here seem to be for straight up replacing the contents of the file which is not what I want.

What I'm trying to accomplish is as follows;
I am making a web project where I have an EXE of our software that customers can download. It currently contains a "static license key" inside the binary of the file when the user downloads it. Obviously we don't want everyone having the same key, so I'd like to make it so that when a certain user downloads it from their panel, it replaces the static key with their personal key. (They are always the same length.)

Up to the replacing part, I seem to have everything working. However, whenever I try and do research on replacing binary/hex with PHP, it always involves overwriting the initial file, making a copy, etc... This is not what I want.

I want to read the file into memory, do the manipulations I need (replace the license key), stream it to the customer for download, and as soon as it's done forget about it and free the memory.

I can't really find any resources at all on accomplishing this, and I'm curiously wondering if it's even possible in PHP. Even if it is, I have concerns about memory usage if say 100-500 people were to all download it at exactly the same time.

Hopefully someone can assist and give some ideas as to how I could accomplish this!

Comment: A simple solution would be to copy the file to a temp file, write to the corresponding bit (`fopen()`, `fseek()`, `fwrite()`...) then stream the file to the user.

Comment: You can read all the file into a string. Manipulate at the appropriate offset where the key is and use a [header with attachment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition).

Comment: If you mind about many people downloading it simultaneosly it would be a good idea to have a 'buffer' of such files already prepared. Make a background job (does not need to be written in PHP) which generates those files in advance and when number in buffer decreases generates more. When someone wants to download the file you serve the first one from the buffer. This also helps for your site performance because PHP which serves the page as well (which I assume) will not be busy with manipulating the file contents.